# How to get state which comes from props which is got from API in React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-props, setstate

## What I want to do

- **When a child component first rendering, I would like to use the value in props from a parent component**

## Problem

- **When a child component is first rendered, props is not set to state in the child component**

I am a beginner to `React`. I am trying to use `props` in order to call API by `axios` in `componentDidMount` in a child component. I mean, what I am doing is calling API in a parent component and setting data from this API to a child component as `props`.

However, when I try to do that, `props` is not set to `state` in a child component.

For example, when I retrieve product which has some `category`, I type `localhost:3000/api/parent/?category=1/`. But, my `console.log` shows me `localhost:3000/api/parent/?category=undefined` because I guess props is not set when a child component first rendering.
Actually, I can see `category` object in `state` like below.

[image]

I guess `props` is completely set to `state` **after the child component finish first rendering.**

How could I set `props` which comes from API to `state`?
Although I tried many solutions I found on the stackoverflow, I got stuck at this problem so long time.

I would like you to tell me some solutions.

Thank you very much.

==  ==  ==

My code is like this.

Parent Component

```
class Top extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loginUser: '',
      categories: [],
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const localhostUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';
    const topCategoryList = ['Smartphone', 'Tablet', 'Laptop'];
    let passCategoryToState=[]
    axios
      .get(localhostUrl + 'user/' + localStorage.getItem('uid'))
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ loginUser: res.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    await Promise.all(
      topCategoryList.map(async (category) => {
        await axios.get(localhostUrl + 'category/?name=' + category).then((res) => {
          passCategoryToState=[...passCategoryToState, res.data]
          console.log(passCategoryToState);
        });
      })
    );

    this.setState({categories : passCategoryToState})
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return <p> Developing now </p>;
    }
    if (this.state.loginUser === '' ) {
      return <CircularProgress />;
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <Header loginUser={this.state.loginUser} />
          <Give_Item_List
            axiosUrl="http://localhost:8000/api/"
            subtitle="Smartphone Items"
            loginUser={this.state.loginUser}
            category={this.state.categories[0]}
          />
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Top;
```

And, child component

```
class Give_Item_List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      loginUser: this.props.loginUser,
      category: this.props.category,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let pickedGiveItems;
    await this.setState({ loading: true });
    await axios
      .get(this.props.axiosUrl + 'giveitem/?category=' + this.state.category.id)
      .then((res) => {
        pickedGiveItems = res.data;
        console.log(pickedGiveItems);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('Not found related to Items'));
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading == true) {
      return <CircularProgress />;
    }
    return <h1>Give_Item_List</h1>;
  }
}

export default Give_Item_List;
```

==============

## Edit:Change to `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.category != this.props.category){
    let pickedGiveItems;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    axios
      .get(this.props.axiosUrl + 'giveitem/?category=' + this.props.category.id)
      .then((res) => {
        pickedGiveItems = res.data;
        console.log(pickedGiveItems);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('NotFount'));
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }
}
```

It still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, `this.props` is undefined, but you can access the props directly.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loading: false,
    loginUser: props.loginUser,
    category: props.category,
  };
}
```

However, I should note now that storing props in state is a common react anti-pattern, you should always consume prop values from `this.props` where you need them.

For example:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  let pickedGiveItems;
  await this.setState({ loading: true });
  await axios
    .get(this.props.axiosUrl + 'giveitem/?category=' + this.props.category.id)
    .then((res) => {
      pickedGiveItems = res.data;
      console.log(pickedGiveItems);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('Not found related to Items'));
  this.setState({ loading: false });
}
```

You also can't `await` a react state update since it isn't an async function nor does it return a Promise. Just provide an initial true loading state and toggle false when the fetch request resolves.

```
class Give_Item_List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let pickedGiveItems;
    
    await axios
      .get(this.props.axiosUrl + 'giveitem/?category=' + this.props.category.id)
      .then((res) => {
        pickedGiveItems = res.data;
        console.log(pickedGiveItems);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('Not found related to Items'));
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <CircularProgress />;
    }
    return <h1>Give_Item_List</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried what I taught to me, but it doesn't work. `Console.log` still says `cateogry.id` is `undefined`...

Comment: @Toshi023Yuki Where are you logging `category.id`? `categories` in the parent component is initially an empty array, so `this.state.categories[0]` passed to the child component will be undefined on the initial render. If you need to react to the `category` prop changing then you should also implement `componentDidUpdate` and do the fetch in the child component when `category.id` changes.

Comment: Honestly, I have never used `componentDidUpdate`. I tried using it like you taught me but it doesn't work. I add my new code about `componentDidUpdate` to my question. If it is alright with you, I would like you to tell what is something wrong.

Comment: @Toshi023Yuki No worries. Can you try creating a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) of your code that reproduces the issue, and share here? It may be easier to live debug the code to see how the props may or may not be changing over time.

Comment: Thank you for you great support. I created a new sandbox. Honesty, I cannot say I created it in a right way but I will share the link with you. This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-lumiere-0hshl?file=/frontend/src/containers/Pages/Top.jsx). You may be required password so I will tell it to you. `username` is guest, and `password` is password000. You may be in trouble because I am creating this app in Japanese. If you feel inconvenience, I am very sorry.

Comment: @Toshi023Yuki Unfortunately I can't get anything to render in that sandbox. Can you try to instead reduce it down to the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue. I think something with the two components you've mentioned could/should be enough. It's the child component not seeing the updated category prop from the parent, right?

Comment: You are right. I am sorry for the inconvenience. I recreated my sandbox. If it is alright with you, I would like you to check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-ritchie-7nxlq?file=/Give_Item_List.jsx). Thank you very much.

Comment: I just tell you I finally solved this issue. Before the component is first rendered, I set a condition which is `this.state.category != ""`. I mean, when child component is first rendered, `props` has already values which comes from API. So, `componentDIdUpdate` didn't work, I guess. Thank you very much.